# Meaning of get into

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

Reading [the article](http://www.english-test.net/lessons/53/index.html), I didn't understand the meaning of "break into" and "get into"

> It's very difficult to break into journalism, meaning it is very
>   difficult to get into a career in journalism.

Consulting with a few dictionaries: [macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-into), [cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-into-sth?q=get%20into) I still don't understand.

Break into (and get into) in this context states that it's very difficult to start enjoying journalism when you're attempting to make a career in it. Correct?

Comment: The answer is right under your nose. It means that it is not easy to start working as a journalist, or start a career in journalism. It has nothing to do with enjoyment.

Comment: Your cited usage *isn't* the idiomatic phrasal verb *(be into = like very much)*. It's just a normal usage - where ***into*** is redundant, and wouldn't always (or even *often*) be included. It's difficult to *break into / obtain / start* a career in journalism.

Comment: @Usernew Look at [this](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+into) _Be interested in or involved with_ I suppose if you're interested in what you're doing you enjoy it more-or-less...

Comment: @DmitriiBundin While "into" is frequently used idiomatically this way, it's pretty clear from the context that that's not what's meant here.

Comment: @Usernew & Era - I think those things are "pretty clear" and "right under your nose" if you are a native English speaker. For learners, the various ways a phrasal verb like _get into_ can be used can be confusing and vexing. [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20into) lists 8 possible meanings, and so does [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-into) – and they don't even all overlap!

Comment: @J.R. I was thinking about this too. It's hard for me to place exactly *why* it seems clear to me. Understanding context is a skill that develops over years of using a language, but it seems to happen largely unconsciously.

Comment: @Era - In my mind, these make for the most interesting ELL questions. It's interesting to think about how and why a seemingly simple wording would be so tricky. If you think about it long enough, though, it begins to make sense. In this case, both "get" and "into" have several meanings, and "get into" has quite a few more. This means there's no small number of possible permutations, and unless you already know which is the correct one, it wouldn't be easy to figure out – even if it is supposedly "right under your nose".

Comment: @J.R. Though interesting it may be. But the OP here did some research before asking the question, however, his research was not well enough. I am no native English speaker, but I understood the meaning, and so my comment. Perhaps you slightly misjudged "the answer is right under your nose."

Comment: @Usernew - We can't expect that every learner will be able to figure out every meaning with the same degree of ease. (If they could, I don't think we'd have many questions on ELL!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Usernew's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/87376/20213) is correct about the meaning of *break into*. The subsequent phrase *get into* is merely clarifying the meaning of *break into*, and is not itself idiomatic (the comments are correct). The purpose of the sentence is explaining an idiomatic expression using a non-idiomatic expression that means the same thing.

Neither phrase has anything to do with enjoying journalism in this context. They both refer to **entering** the field of journalism, and it is in that sense that you get **into** (the field of) journalism.

Comment: One could argue that _get into_ is just as idiomatic as _break into_. It's at least as metaphorical, I think.

Comment: @J.R. IMO, there isn't really a strict distinction in English between figurative and non-figurative language. I think this particular example could arguably be considered a dead metaphor, but it's not really idiomatic.

Comment: I agree, to a point. I'm just trying to analyze this phrase the way a novice learner might. If I were a learner trying to parse _get into journalism_, I might start by looking up the word _get_, where I'd get [lost in a hurry](http://www.onelook.com/?w=get&ls=a). I might then figure out that _get into_ is a phrasal verb, but even that has [multiple meanings](http://www.onelook.com/?w=get+into&ls=a). And getting into journalism isn't quite the same thing as getting into a car; to me, this seems somewhere in the fuzzy space between metaphoric, figurative, and idiomatic figures of speech.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: not quite.  They are simply saying that it is difficult to start a career in journalism.

Additionally, both *break into* and *get into* in this case have the meaning of becoming a part of something, typically some sort of group.  However, *break into* also has the implication that the accomplishment is difficult, without actually having to say so.  For example:

> If my novel is as good as I think it is, I should be able to break into writing as a career.
>   It's harder for a woman to break into the executive level of a corporation than it is for a man.

*Get into* doesn't have that same sense of difficulty:

> I'm going to get into writing.
>   I'm going to get into Sunday School teaching.

Now, another meaning of *break into* is burgle, as in *break into a house.*

Comment: Good answer. One quick footnote, if I may: sometimes, _get into_ **is** used when there's some degree of difficulty involved (for example, "Linda is trying to get into Harvard"). It all depends on the exclusivity of what  you're trying to get into.

Comment: @J.R. That's true too, and a good point.  I guess I should say that *get into* doesn't automatically have that implication where *break into* does.

Answer (score 1):

*[Break into](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-phrasal-verb-definition.php?d=275)*<sup>1</sup> is a phrasal verb which also means **to successfully start a business or get into a profession.**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/break--into) gives the following meaning:

> to be admitted into; enter, as a business or profession:

Also, here is an excerpt from a book:

> [image]

---

<sup>1. myenglishpages.com</sup>